# OpsHub migration gets stuck with error

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

`OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. The HTTP request timed out after 00:01:40.`

Retry doesn't appear to do anything. according to the logs say:

`2015-08-26 16:59:47,086 [3] DEBUG Getting all changesets that were created after + 695
2015-08-26 16:59:47,198 [3] DEBUG Retrived total 0 changesets created after 695.`

The UI clearly shows that `967/2472 changeset(s)/label(s) passed.`

Which is even more odd, since there are > 8900 changesets

[image]
My configuration is history only with labels, no work items.

Comment: Hi, Is it a single project migration or multiple ones? Can you try doing "View History" at the collection level through Visual Studio Source Control Explorer and see what is the last changeset? It's quite possible, there are no changesets left to be processed and only labels are left.

Comment: single project migration, last changeset as of today is `8964`

Comment: Hi, if you view History at collection level, it will also show changesets of other projects in that collection as well. For the timeout, can you try increasing the value in <installation-path>/Other_Resources/Resources/TFSUtility/TFSService/opshubtfsservice.exe.config through a text editor.

Comment: I increased the timeouts to 4 minutes, they were at 2. The log says it is still timing out after 1 minute and 40 seconds.